# Axiom or theorem: in triangle $a+b > c$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Suddenly I am confused by a very elementary question:

> Let $a, b, c$ be the sides of a triangle. How about this inequality: 
>   $$ a+b > c. $$

Is it the definition of a triangle or is it a theorem?

Comment: It can be proved in Euclidean geometry, see [The Elements I-20](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI20.html).

Comment: @Aretino : Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Whether it's a theorem or an axiom depends very much on how you approach your geometry. If you approach it from analysis, basing everything on a defined notion of distance, then it's an axiom. (It's one of the relatively few properties we generally require that this "distance", called a *metric*, fulfills. Although, if you want it specifically to model the planar geometry we're used to, you need additional requirements, of course.)

If you approach it more clasically, basing everything on points and lines and congruences, then it's usually a theorem. (Note that the triangle inequality may be proven long before you prove that there is a consistent way of assigning lengths to segments, since consistent notions of "this segment is longer than that segment" and "putting two segments together" is a lot more basic than that.)

Comment: @A rthur : Thank you. Very kind answer!

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the law of cosines:
$$
c^2 = a^2+b^2 - 2ab \cos \hat C
\le  a^2+b^2 + 2ab
= (a+b)^2
$$

Comment: One doubt - Don't we have to define a triangle first and then talk about law of cosines, although this answer fits perfectly, but I don't understand how can we use this in this scenario ? Can we say all triangles obey this law so to be a triangle this is required ? Thank you!

Comment: Samjoe. Aretino's link: Euclid I-20 may be of interest.

Comment: @lhf : I see your idea,,and have thanks,, but  I have a dout  if that ; the law of cosine is based on the triangle inequality?,,